# Fix graphics driver Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xubuntu

While configuring Lutris, I accidentally installed the wrong video card drivers. I followed the steps for Nvidia and the steps listed for "If you have Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver or Ubuntu 18.10 Cosmic Cuttlefish:"
https://github.com/lutris/lutris/wiki/Installing-drivers

After rebooting, I'm no longer able to access my desktop, only the command line. I have tried removing the installed packages with
sudo apt remove --purge nvidia*
and
sudo apt remove --purge libnvidia*
and the same command for the other packages listed. The packages were removed successfully, but with no effect on the GUI.

I also tried running lightdm from the command line but received an error message.

I am running Xubuntu 18.04 on an [Asus x200ma](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/X200MA/specifications/) with an [Intel 'Bay Trail' Atom APU](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/codename/55844/bay-trail.html) providing HD graphics.

Comment: To start with, what commands did you use to _remove_ the NVIDIA driver, and what did you see when you ran those commands? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]. And, https://www.reddit.com/r/vulkan/comments/bt926d/warnings_with_baytrail/ reports Vulkan support for Bay Trail graphics is _incomplete_.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg
sudo apt --resinstall install xorg
```

I also had to reset Xauthority privileges: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=togIj3hfbDs